# how to check if a button was clicked in another button code in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I wanted to check if I could call a button in another button code or check if it had been clicked immediately before that button. have search with homeandlearn.uk and google search but couldn't get the right result

Comment: What do you mean immediately? How many seconds? Should the first button enable/disable the second button? Maybe if you elaborate on the end goal here we can suggest something better than what you envision now.

Answer (score 0):

If you need one button(Button1) clicked before another(Button2), you can find it easier to only enable the second in the click event handler of the first button.  Set the Button2.Enabled property to false in the designer then something like this would work:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Button2.Enabled = True
End Sub
```